# Conditional update with Elastic Search Client with mongoose static

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I have a `mongoose` schema and when the save or update is called on this, in turns it updates the elastic search source as well. I have one issue when the `status` value is `draft` it should not update the elastic search. How it can be achieved by making the modification in following schema?

```
var TestShcema = new mongoose.Schema({
        custom_id:{
            type:String,
            required: true,
            index: {unique: true},
            es_indexed: true,
            es_index:"analyzed",
            es_index_analyzer:"autocomplete_analyzer"
        },
        title:{
            type:String,
            index: {unique: false},
            es_indexed: true,
            es_index:"analyzed",
            es_index_analyzer:"autocomplete_analyzer"
        },
        status:{
            type:String,
            index: {unique: false},
            es_indexed: true,
            es_index:"analyzed",
            es_index_analyzer:"autocomplete_analyzer"
        }
    });
    //Hook with Elastic Search
    var esClient = new elasticsearch.Client({host: config.elasticsearch.host});

    TestShcema.plugin(mongoosastic, {
        esClient: esClient
    });

    var Test = mongoose.model('Test', TestShcema);

    module.exports = Test;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Filtered Indexing

copy paste from npmjs

You can specify a filter function to index a model to Elasticsearch based on some specific conditions.

**Filtering function must return True for conditions that will ignore indexing to Elasticsearch.**

```
var MovieSchema = new Schema({
  title: {type: String},
  genre: {type: String, enum: ['horror', 'action', 'adventure', 'other']}
});

MovieSchema.plugin(mongoosastic, {
  filter: function(doc) {
    return doc.genre === 'action';
  }
});
```

Instances of Movie model having '**action**' as their genre will not be indexed to Elasticsearch.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoosastic#filtered-indexing

you can do something like this

```
TestShcema.plugin(mongoosastic, {
  filter: function(doc) {
    return doc.status === 'draft';
  }
});
```